# Can't run jmeter on OS x (El Capitan)

Tags: java, macos, jmeter

I'm working on a web project and I want to integrate JMeter to run some load tests. I'm following this simple [tutorial](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/load-testing-jmeter-part-1-getting-started/). I have installed JMeter using brew. When I try to run JMeter, I get the following error: Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.

Previously I have installed de last version of java (https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp) and I have verified it on https://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp. I get this message "Congratulations! You have the recommended Java installed (Version 8 Update 91)." But I can't run JMeter. How should I configure my Java or JMeter installation for the run?

Comment: hmm maybe you should set $JAVA_HOME environment variable

Comment: I set export `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`on my .bash_profile file, but it is not working. when I run `wich java`, I get `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home`, no need for `$`(actually `$` is wrong), you have to `source ~/.bash_profile`, `which java` has no relation to `JAVA_HOME`, instead issue `env | grep JAVA_HOME` or try to execute jmeter

Comment: Ok, I setted `source JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home`, If I run `env | grep JAVA_HOME` I get `JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home`. But when I run `/usr/libexec/java_home` I get _Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)". No Java runtime present, try --request to install._ :(

Comment: that's because it's not supposed for JAVA_HOME to point to where `java` executable is but to where $JAVA_HOME/bin contains java executable ;)

Comment: ok, I found the bug... Download java directly from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html, and not from here https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp.

Answer (score 1):

The Java check in the `jmeter` wrapper script incorrectly handles spaces in path names.

The path to the java binary on macOS is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`, with a space in the path.

Edit `/usr/local/brew/Cellar/jmeter/3.0/libexec/bin/jmeter` and comment out the version check block at the top as a workaround.

Comment: There is no such identified issue. You need to use the correct version of Java compatible with version of JMeter

Answer (score 1):

For having a working JMeter installation on MacOS, the latest **compatible** Java SDK needs to be installed from the [Oracle Java SE page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Once on that main page, you should go to the "Java Platform, Standard Edition" page and then download and install the Mac OS X .dmg file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on version, JMeter is compatible with certain version of Java.

As of 3.3, it is only compatible with Java 8 (select last minor update)

On Mac OSX, you can have a look at this to make it run easily:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/using-homebrew-to-install-and-configure-jmeter-under-mac-osx/

But otherwise , having it run on Mac OSX is as easy as:

- Downloading the JDK compatible with the version (8 for 3.3)
- Installing it
- Downloading jmeter and reading release notes:

> http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

- Running /bin/jmeter.sh